# Style binding and class binding

Tags: angular

Why do we need style binding and class binding in Angular instead of using HTML style and traditional class?
Example:

```
<img src="link_img" [style.width]="imgWidth">
```

instead of

```
<img src="link_img" width="200">
```

Hope anyone explain for me...
Thanks for reading

Comment: You can do both. Angular style binding is dynamic which you can also control from your typescript code.

Comment: All HTML attributes are bindable to make your view dynamic and style is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because using the first syntax allows you to change the attributes given conditions.

Let's say you want, for instance, a bigger image on computer screens, and a smaller image on phone screens :

```
<img [style.width]="isOnPhone ? '50%' : '100%'">
```

This isn't that useful in this particular case because CSS can handle that, but imagine all the possibilities :

```
<div class="user-informations" [style.display]="isUserConnected ? 'block' : 'none'">
<button type="submit" [disabled]="isFormValid ? false : true">
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

And the next step for applying multiple styles would be to use ngStyle in the template.

```
<p [ngStyle]="styles">
  I'm stylish!
</p>
```

And then to define a property in the component that contains an object with css properties as keys like so.

```
styles = {
  border: '3px dotted blue',
  fontSize': '22px',
  fontWeight: 'bold'
}
```